# What set is this green sled from?

Tags: set-identification

Anyone know what LEGO set this little green sled is from? The pieces rest on a black 6x4 studded plate. The corner cheese wedges and edge rails on the right and left are a dark green (not black).

[image: Green sled]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is part of Set # [10198-1: Tantive IV](https://brickset.com/sets/10198-1/Tantive-IV)

[image]

based on the [Dark green Panel 1 x 2 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4865&idColor=80#T=C&C=80) and
[Tile 1 x 2 with Avionics SW Copper, Red & Silver Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3069bps2&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)